# Repeat each item in a list based on condition in a df column

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame, and a list. The pandas data frame has 2 columns State and dates.

```
State   Dates
0       1/1/2023
1       2/1/2023
2       3/1/2023
3       4/1/2023
0       1/1/2023
1       2/1/2023
0       1/1/2023
1       2/1/2023
2       3/1/2023
0       1/1/2023
1       2/1/2023
2       3/1/2023
3       4/1/2023
4       5/1/2023
5       6/1/2023
...

country = [A, B, C, D,...]
```

Every time State is 0 , it should also add new item from the list corresponding to the iteration, in a new column called 'country'.

```
State   Dates      country
0       1/1/2023     A
1       2/1/2023     A
2       3/1/2023     A
3       4/1/2023     A
0       1/1/2023     B
1       2/1/2023     B
0       1/1/2023     C
1       2/1/2023     C
2       3/1/2023     C
0       1/1/2023     D
1       2/1/2023     D
2       3/1/2023     D
3       4/1/2023     D
4       5/1/2023     D
5       6/1/2023     D
```

How  can get to the result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
country = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

df["Country"] = df.groupby(df["State"].eq(0).cumsum())["State"].transform(
    lambda _, i=iter(country): next(i, None)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    State     Dates Country
0       0  1/1/2023       A
1       1  2/1/2023       A
2       2  3/1/2023       A
3       3  4/1/2023       A
4       0  1/1/2023       B
5       1  2/1/2023       B
6       0  1/1/2023       C
7       1  2/1/2023       C
8       2  3/1/2023       C
9       0  1/1/2023       D
10      1  2/1/2023       D
11      2  3/1/2023       D
12      3  4/1/2023       D
13      4  5/1/2023       D
14      5  6/1/2023       D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple cycle over a column to achieve that:

```
def get_countries(states, country_list):
    countries = []
    current_country_idx = -1
    
    for state in states:
        if state == 0:
            current_country_idx += 1
        countries.append(country_list[current_country_idx])
    
    return countries

df["Country"] = get_countries(df["State"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    State     Dates Country
0       0  1/1/2023       A
1       1  2/1/2023       A
2       2  3/1/2023       A
3       3  4/1/2023       A
4       0  1/1/2023       B
5       1  2/1/2023       B
6       0  1/1/2023       C
7       1  2/1/2023       C
8       2  3/1/2023       C
9       0  1/1/2023       D
10      1  2/1/2023       D
11      2  3/1/2023       D
12      3  4/1/2023       D
13      4  5/1/2023       D
14      5  6/1/2023       D
```

Answer (score 1):

**1/ My Solution (2 lines - no loop, no if)**

```
import pandas as pd

# Step 0 - Create inputs : Sample DataFrame
data = {'state': [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Step 0 - Create inputs : Sample list of countries
countries = ["country1", "country2", "country3"]

# Step 1 - Treat rows with 0 state: Add country for each row with state 0
df.loc[df["state"] == 0, "country"] = countries

# Step 2 - Treat other rows: Fill na values with last known value
df["country"].ffill(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

**2/ The output dataframe**

```
   state   country
0      0  country1
1      1  country1
2      0  country2
3      1  country2
4      2  country2
5      0  country3
6      1  country3
7      2  country3
8      3  country3
9      4  country3
```

**3/ The constraint**

Your list of countries must have as many items (aka countries) as the number of rows with 0 state in your dataframe.
If you want to loop in the list of countries, consider the comment of @Jab.

Comment: You could use `itertools.cycle` on the countries list to cycle back to the original country when exhaustedif this is desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# given data frame
data = {
    'State': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Dates': ['1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', '3/1/2023', '4/1/2023', 
              '1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', 
              '3/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', '3/1/2023', 
              '4/1/2023', '5/1/2023', '6/1/2023']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#the list of countries
countries = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# intitalize list of countrys
country_counter = 0

# Iterate through the country list and assign a value to it
df['country'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['State'] == 0:
        country_counter = (country_counter + 1) % len(countries)
    df.at[index, 'country'] = countries[country_counter]

# display the data frame
print(df)
```

here is the code, you have to iterate through the pandas data frame

Answer (score 1):

You can do a for loop through all dataframe rows, and each time you find a row with State "0" you change into the next country. For changing from country to country you can use the [list pop method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-pop-method/), but will need to change the order of the list first.  Something like this:

```
# You start with no "current" country (the if statement will assign it later)
current_country = None

# Reverse the order of the country list (so "A" is the first to be assigned)
country.reverse()  

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # this `if` is only true when you need to change countries 
    if row['State'] == 0:
        # pop returns the last item of the list, and removes it from the list
        current_country = country.pop(0)
    # then you assign the country to the new column 
    df.at[index, 'country'] = current_country
```